# Summing two 2-D lists

Tags: python-3.x

so this has kind of stumped me. I feel like it should be an easy problem though. 
Lets say I have these two lists

```
a = [[3, 4], [4, 5]]
b = [[1, 2], [4, 6]]
```

I am trying so it would return the sum of the two 2-D lists of each corresponding element like so

```
c = [[4, 6], [8, 11]]
```

I am pretty sure I am getting lost in loops. I am only trying to use nested loops to produce an answer, any suggestions? I'm trying several different things so my code is not exactly complete or set in stone and will probably change by the time someone reponds so I won't leave a code here. I am trying though!

Comment: Is it guaranteed that each list of lists will have the same number of elements and that each list at a given index in the list of lists will have the same number of elements?

Comment: @JamesRobinson Robison yes it is. I have a conditional statement prior to test whether the lengths of the list are equal and returns False if they are not

Answer (score 1):

You could try some variation on nested for-loops using enumerate (which will give you the appropriate indices for comparison to some other 2d array):

```
a = [[3, 4], [4, 5]]
b = [[1, 2], [4, 6]]
```

Edit: I didn't see you wanted to populate a new list, so I put that in there:

```
>>> c = []
>>> for val, item in enumerate(a):
        newvals = []
        for itemval, insideitem in enumerate(item):
           newvals.append(insideitem + b[val][itemval])
         c.append(newvals)
         newvals = []
```

Result:

```
>>> c
[[4, 6], [8, 11]]
```

Comment: sorry it took me a little while to understand your code I get it now Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If it worked and solved the problem, general practice is to accept an answer. It marks the question as solved for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

a = [[3, 4], [4, 5]]
b = [[1, 2], [4, 6]]
c = np.array((a,b))
np.sum(c, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, but following nested loops code works exactly as desired by OP:

```
sumlist = []
for i, aa in enumerate(a):
    for j, bb in enumerate(b): 
        if i == j: 
            templist = []
            for k in range(2):
                templist.append(aa[k]+bb[k])
            sumlist.append(templist)
            templist = []
print(sumlist)
```

Output:

```
[[4, 6], [8, 11]]
```